# Snort Rule to Detect Single JS or VBS file in ZIP file

Tags: security, snort

How can I make use of Snort rule to find ZIP files being downloaded that contain only a **single** .js or .vbs file?

Thought of using pcre -> **^PK.+.(js|JS|Js|jS)**

**Sample of traffic:**

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 19 Apr 2017 19:46:43 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires: Tue, 08 Jan 1935 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
filename="document__917_8324_94_Apr___19___2017_09__44___27.zip"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

4295b
**PK**...........JV...M(...G..<...**document__59020_001366_8039__Apr___19___2017__09__44___27.js**UT    .....X...Xux...............gs.L.-.~?..?P.(
%R.<..e...TH.@..n.......[.2..4.g.{..{....s...&......2.w..V.;u.f.'.....3<........m<..>..8..Z.K6...k.....q.7...v4z........_.....)...w..Zosw......X.4..2."..z>..o.....Q6.G.A6.i.......Muz..T.}.kf..z.W..._O......J.#.;S.{....,..k...z...lu.Y;.J..^.......P=[..jg.m65..........SY.1..F..z{.L..,.L...~o.Me..V.....a}<.N
.....x....;..]..~T..n...G........z>..o.Y.........M...+.z...^.P_w.(...|.2.,.{.]...........W..;.......lL...Wv..p..r..1}.........]...r..Wwg.gYr....>.-..6.....:+.'..~.1...?.Nj'G_..........m...r...r..S.m.W.....<......wE...f.E....a...M

Comment: Sorry I can't answer this question, but just to let you know, you can select code and then press CTRL+K. That will format selected text as code. Or hard way - manually add 4 spaces before each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"TEST"; file_data; content:"|0D 0A 0D 0A 50 4B|"; nocase; pcre:"/\x0D\x0A\x0D\x0APK.+?\.js/i"; sid:1000000;)
```

`content:"|0D 0A 0D 0A 50 4B|";` option is matched with `....PK`

And `i` option of PCRE means ignore case sensitive.

[image]

And `file_data` option inspect http response. http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node32.html#SECTION004528000000000000000